# Scraping Facebook Ad Library Reports

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script that would download [Facebook Ad Library Reports](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/report/?source=archive-landing-page&country=UA).

While inspecting the page I found a link that is triggered once I click "Download Report" button, but it doesn't work with simple requests.get apparently.

My attempt:

```py
import requests

endpoint = 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/report/v2/download/'
params = (
    ('report_ds', '2020-09-21'),
    ('country', 'UA'),
    ('time_preset', 'yesterday'),
)

response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
print(response.content)
b''
```

Comment: If you check in your browser dev tools, you see that clicking this “link” actually causes a POST request, and it sends a lot of additional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no need to scrape, Facebook offers an API for that - you have to verify before accessing it :)

https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/

Comment: Downloading the Library report CSV has other information, like page IDs that can be used with the API. It can be useful to automate that.